# How to check programmatically if the option "Use GPS Satellite" in the setting is ticked

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, start-activity, onactivityresult

How to check programmatically if the option "Use GPS Satellite" in the setting menu of the device is ticked?

Any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "use gps satellite", the user can turn on/off gps, what is this setting?

Comment: I will assume that, you will access the settings activity by calling `startactivity`. but since, you want to check if the user ticked an option or not, then, you should use `startactivityforresult` because you are expecting a value returned from that activity "the setting activity". is that nearly your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using broadcast receiver you can achieve this.

```
public class GPSStatusBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Broadcast received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Add this to the android manifest, inside the tags:

```
<receiver android:name=".GPSStatusBroadcastReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check GPS Check by using this code.

```
LocationManager myLocationManager;
LocationListener myLocationListener; 

    myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();


    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocationListener);
            if(!myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ))
            {
                displayalert(); 
            }
```

Comment: actually, this is not the case. because based on the user choice "whether he ticked the gps-enable or not" i should do some actions or initialize certain views

Comment: I will assume that, you will access the settings activity by calling `startactivity`. but since, you want to check if the user ticked an option or not, then, you should use `startactivityforresult` because you are expecting a value returned from that activity "the setting activity". is that nearly your case?